# Create a dict from a list that contains no keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have lists of values as seen below:

```
[(51, 4889.37), (58, 5582.51), (62, 6005.07), (67, 6533.27)]
```

I obtain the list above by using the append within a for loop where Mw_Price is Mw(51) and Price(4889.37) for each iteration

```
 new_list.append(Mw_Price)
```

Is there an append to a dict?

I need my output to be as such:

```
 [{'Mw': 51,  'Price': 4889.37} , {'Mw': 58,  'Price': 5582.51} , {'Mw': 62,  'Price': 6533.27}],
```

Comment: When you're appending, why don't you just append a dict instead of a tuple?

Comment: Why don't you simply `append({'Mv':...})`?

Answer (score 1):

From your rough description of your code (please include *actual* code for best answers), you can probably do something like:

```
new_list.append({'Mw': Mw_Price[0], 'Price': Mw_Price[1]})
```

to get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.  I think I was over complicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably better unpack the pairs into two separate variables in the first place:

```
old_list = [(51, 4889.37), (58, 5582.51), (62, 6005.07), (67, 6533.27)]
new_list = [{'Mw': mw, 'Price': price} for mw, price in old_list]
```

Or if you insist on loop-and-append:

```
for mw, price in old_list:
    new_list.append({'Mw': mw, 'Price': price})
```